# Show values with blanks

Tags: java, android, string

I need to concatenate string but in this way. For example:
name1 = its an String value and
best1 = its an integer value;

```
String shareBody = name1 + "" + ":" + "" + String.valueOf(best1); //Wrong
```

And I need to show the following:
Output:

```
Jake : 50
Pol  : 60
Gian : 70
```

how can i do this?

Comment: what is wrong in that?

Comment: well, are you ever tried to actually put a space? "" is not a space, its an empty string, you should write:  name1 + " : " + String.valueOf(best1);

Comment: @Shermano to be 100% correct, it should be `name1 + " = " + String.valueOf(best1);` =)

Comment: @Turing85 To be 100% correct it should be `name1 + " : " + String.valueOf(best1);` :)

Comment: @Nexevis welp, OP's wording is a little bit confusing. In the description, `=` is used while in code, `:` is used :D (just notices that `=` could be meant as a non-literal symobl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the following. `best1` will be automatically cast to a string in this case.

```
String shareBody = name1 + " : " + best1;
```

Answer (score 8):

the best way is to use [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) like so :

```
String shareBody = String.format("%s : %d", name1, best1);
```

---

about the `%s` and `%d` is a String and Integer holders, the `format` method will parse the `"%s = %d"` and replace each holder with the corresponding value, so for `%s` will be replace by the value of `name1` and `%d` will be replace with the value of `best1`.

For more details take a look at the documentation.